# Android: Notify user of a newer version

Tags: android, updates

I am finding alot of users for some reason are not upgrading my application when new versions come out.
Is there a way for my application to query the Marketplace application and then notify the user if a newer version is available ?

Comment: If the user are not upgrading, this means they don't want to upgrade. You shouldn't force them to upgrade, and you definitely should not nag them with an upgrade notification each time they're opening your apps (unless you want your user to be annoyed and uninstall your application)

Comment: Android Market will already notify the user if they have apps with upgrades available.

Comment: Chris, I totally agree with you and think notifying users of new version is smart! Many unsophisticated users don't upgrade because they don't know how. Offering a friendly dialog when they go back into your app and suggesting they upgrade is a good way to help insure users are on the current version. Only way I know to do it though is to write your own webservice.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I don't think it's quite that black and white. Lets say you've made a mistake somewhere in your app. You fix it and deploy to market. But you see from your crash reports that there are old versions out there and same users keep on using this app. If the same user keeps on using the app, wouldn't they rather use a version that does not crash? At some point they uninstall and log their rating as "zero stars, useless had to uninstall" - even though the problem is already fixed.

I agree that it is not a good idea to create duplicate logic that just notifies users about newer versions being available - but sometimes it makes sense to add a little extra notification telling users that updating is for their own good.

One solution, that I just came across today, addressing this issues, is from crash report service Bugsense. It allows to you send a notification to users that a certain error he/she has encountered has been fixed. I think it's just good service and tells users that development has not stopped.

Comment: I like this answer. Short of implementing this capability, a generic "something went wrong" dialog could also remind users to check for new updates.

Answer (score 3):

> I am finding alot of users for some reason are not upgrading my application when new versions come out.

To echo the comments, users are not compelled to upgrade your app.

> Is there a way for my application to query the Marketplace application and then notify the user if a newer version is available ?

No.

Your application can query your own Web server, where you publish version information. However, you need to be a bit careful about this, as there are multiple Market servers, and not all receive updates simultaneously, AFAICT. IOW, I would use this as more of a fall-back mechanism, to perhaps do a one-time "hey, don't forget, there's an update available" notice perhaps a week or two after you publish your update.

Comment: New Android Market pushes notifications for app updates directly to users "if the user has enabled this feature" So i think we do not need to re-invent the wheel ...

Comment: @megazoid: how can I do that using google-play push service ?! .. please point me to a tutorial if you can .. thanks

Comment: @Rania-Boy Well, this is an in-built feature, as soon as you upload a new APK version onto the Play Store, it pushes the notification asking the users to update their current APP.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to have a DB field with the current version on your server, and check the app version with the version mentioned in the back-end server every time the app loads.

But as CommonsWare mentioned, it might irritate some users.

Another possibility is to have an Check for Update button as I do inside the app itself.

Hope this helps....

Comment: This is also a good policy to have. Sometimes an app might be considered too old, but there is a decision point available to notify the user with a message or block the client entirely with a message.