# How can I update my application programmatically?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)

I have an android application. my user install it. how can I notify the user that a new version is available.

my application is not in Market.

thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [link][1]:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635042/android-notify-user-of-a-newer-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two models that are basically used to tackle the issue.

1. Pull based
2. Push Based

Its depends on the architecture or design of particular system that determines whether pull based or push mechanism is used.

1. For pull based model you just make  one http request to concerned server regarding the new version of application. The current application version no can be saved in SQLLite in android application. This can be given to server and new version can be checked against it at the server.
2. For push mechanism you can use GCM push notification service.. details of which are given at [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have users using your application, and you want to notify them, as far as i can tell:

If your application does not already have built in system to check for updates, there is no way for you to know where (on which device) your application is deployed, therefore you cannot notify users about new version...

To overcome this in future, you should include link or button in your application preferences, that will check for new version when user clicks it...

If you are only starting to develop application:
C2DM is the sollution. Check answer from relsell for details.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this project from CommosGuy: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater

It is an updater to update your application outside of the Google Play / Market

This is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: CWAC Updater development is suspended/abandoned: "Work on this project has been suspended — please seek alternative solutions at this time"