# Is there a way using Google play store API to fetch updates of particular installed app from the phone

Tags: android, google-play-services

Apologize I am not a native English speaker.

I want to make an app to fetch information like (list of updates current available in play store ) of an installed app, And I want to preview that updates to the user on a textview.

So is this possible using  Google play store API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no ad hoc API for this feature yet. 
But there are workarounds that you can implement:

- [Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666381/how-can-i-make-my-outdated-app-version-show-a-dialog-that-an-update-is-available?noredirect=1&lq=1): Build the alert dialog on the first version.
- [Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298106/how-to-allow-users-to-check-for-the-latest-app-version-from-inside-the-app): Fire an Intent to open up the Market app hopefully which will cause it to check for updates.